# Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

Ive created a app/helpers.php file then autoloaded in /composer.json.

When I run the composer update I get

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
  Error Output: